# errors package in golang: What is the purpose of the for loop in errors package of Golang when the body of the loop is executed only once?

Tags: go

this is Is function in errors package:

```golang
func Is(err, target error) bool {
    if target == nil {
        return err == target
    }

    isComparable := reflectlite.TypeOf(target).Comparable()
    for {
        if isComparable && err == target {
            return true
        }
        if x, ok := err.(interface{ Is(error) bool }); ok && x.Is(target) {
            return true
        }
        switch x := err.(type) {
        case interface{ Unwrap() error }:
            err = x.Unwrap()
            if err == nil {
                return false
            }
        case interface{ Unwrap() []error }:
            for _, err := range x.Unwrap() {
                if Is(err, target) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of the for loop in errors package of Golang when the body of the loop is executed only once?

Comment: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.5:src/errors/wrap.go;l=44

Comment: In `case interface{ Unwrap() error }:`, if `err` is _not_ nil, the loop repeats.

Comment: The formal answer to your question would be "There is **no purpose** to the for loop when the body of the loop is executed only once." But as Biffen and the documentation of the function explains: The loop _is_ repeated (albeit it's well hidden and could deserve a comment or a redundant continue.

Answer (score 0):

The **Is** function in the Go **errors** package is used to determine whether an error is equal to a particular target error. This function is particularly useful when you're working with wrapped errors, as it can look into the chain of errors (created using **fmt.Errorf** with %w or explicit error wrapping) to find if any error in the chain matches the target error.

Here's a breakdown of why the **for** loop is necessary and how it works:

- The purpose of the for loop is not to execute only once but to continuously unwrap the error until there are no more errors to unwrap or until a match is found. An error might be wrapped multiple times, creating a chain of errors. The loop keeps unwrapping and checking each error in the chain.
- Checking Conditions and Unwrapping:

**isComparable && err == target**: This checks if the current error is directly comparable to the target and if they are equal. If this condition is true, the function returns true immediately.

**err.(interface{ Is(error) bool })**: This checks if the current error has an Is method and whether that method returns true for the target error. This is a way for custom error types to define what they consider an equal error.

**err.(interface{ Unwrap() error })**: This checks if the current error can be unwrapped into another error. If it can, the loop continues with the unwrapped error.

**err.(interface{ Unwrap() []error })**: This checks if the current error can be unwrapped into a slice of errors (this is less common but supports scenarios where an error might be a collection of errors). It then iterates through each unwrapped error, checking if any match the target using recursion.

The loop continues until one of these conditions is met:

- A match is found (return true).
- There are no more errors to unwrap (err becomes nil or doesn't implement Unwrap()).
- No match is found after unwrapping all errors (return false).

The reason it might seem like the body of the loop is executed only once in some scenarios is that many errors aren't wrapped or are only wrapped once. In these cases, the function might return during the first iteration of the loop. However, for deeply nested or chained errors, the loop allows the function to dig through each layer until it finds a match or exhausts all options. This loop ensures that even if errors are wrapped multiple times in different layers, **Is** can still compare them against the target error effectively.